# Mysql, how to select rows that has lower value and put them into array?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table that looks like this

```
videoid | amount | amount2
aaaa      1000        0    
bbbb      1001        0
cccc      1001      1001
dddd      1001       999
```

How do I select videoid's where 'amount2' is equal or more than 'amount' and put them into array, and in case there are no rows like that, to put just one predefined text into array

Comment: MySQL does not support arrays, so you cannot put values into an array.  Further, `'cccc'` meets your condition.  You should show the results you want to get.

Comment: Basically what I want to do is to select random videoid from videoids that meets that condition and in case there are noone to set result for example to eeee

Comment: Post us some of your tries, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `UNION` of two queries. One query returns all the rows that satisfy your condition, the other query returns a specified row if the there are no rows that satisfy the condition.

```
SELECT *
FROM video_table
WHERE amount2 >= amount

UNION 

SELECT *
FROM video_table
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM video_table WHERE amount2 > amount)
AND videoid = "eeee"
```

Comment: Thank you, had to re-edit the code but got it working, basically i added *empty* checker, if the result is empty ~> echo 'with my predefined id' if not echo 'the result from query

Comment: So instead of doing it as a single query, you just did the condition in PHP?

Comment: I did it in single query, but: "the other query returns a random row if the there are no rows that satisfy the condition" instead of random, i needed to display id that is not in the database (predefined), so the empty helps a lot in this case, if there are no id that satisfies condition. Thank you for your help, wish i could add rep

Comment: I must have misread the question, I thought it said to select a random row.

Comment: I've changed the query to select a predefined row.

Comment: Actually I ran into a new problem, query does not work as it should, seems like it checks every other row by probably the first row amount, in other words, each row isn't checked by its two values e.g amount, amount2. Maybe its some sort of a bug, but when i edited table numbers just to check, everything started to mess up, when all the values were same it worked flawesly

Comment: That's not how `WHERE` clauses work, they don't compare between different rows unless you use a self-join.

Comment: You should post a new question with this problem. Include the sample data that's producing the wrong result.

Comment: I dont need to compare between two rows, I need to compare row by its two values (columns), and do the same for all other rows (independently) yes, maybe I should post new q, anyways thanks for your help, hope I dont wasted too much of your time

Comment: My query doesn't compare between two rows, why do you think it is?

Comment: That was response to 'they don't compare between different'

Comment: Right, I'm saying that it doesn't do what you claim it's doing, because there's no join.

Comment: Is there any way to compare each row's values independently?

Comment: That IS what it does.

Comment: With your sample data, it should return the `cccc` row.

Comment: It should, but if you switch the greater or equal to different side, from the 3 rows, only 2 gets randomly returned, one, the middle one never shows up, maybe thats how rand() works but I've refreshed the page nearly 100 times

Comment: What does `rand()` have to do with it? Please post the data that's causing the problem.

Comment: I have to leave now, I'll check back tomorrow.

Comment: So i finally found the issue, my problem was that i setted the wrong data type for sql columns, instead of VARCHAR i changed it to INT